# Change scene in full screen JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX. I have my main and secondary scenes; when I change from the first scene to the second one, the window's bar becomes visible. How can I fix that?

Here is my code

```
public class ProyectoTeoriaBD1 extends Application {

Stage primaryStage;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();
    gp.setHgap(10);
    gp.setVgap(10);
    gp.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));

    Scene firstScene = new Scene(gp);
    Button b = new Button("Change Scene");        
    gp.add(b,1,1);
    primaryStage.setScene(firstScene);
     primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.show();



   b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
           GridPane gp = new GridPane();
           Scene secondScene = new Scene(gp);
           Text txtSecond = new Text("Second Scene");
           gp.add(txtSecond, 1, 1);
           primaryStage.setScene(secondScene);
           primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
           primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);

        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullscreen stage is not working properly in JavaFX 2.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273378/fullscreen-stage-is-not-working-properly-in-javafx-2-1)

Answer (score 2):

A full runnable testable code could be helpful. Also provide your system environment details. I have tested your code below (try yourself) which works on my windows 7 64 bit with JavaFX version 2.2.0.
(I will update my answer as you provide more details and lastly welcome to stackoverflow!)

**Update:** Ok I guess your primary stage was in full screen mode initially. In that case you need to toggle full screen mode. See below.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        Button btn = new Button("Login");
        btn.setOnAction(loginClienteHandler());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX version: " + com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public EventHandler loginClienteHandler() {
        EventHandler evh = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create().children(new Text("text")).build()));
                primaryStage.sizeToScene();
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            }
        };
        return evh;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying, now i have edite my question so you can see what i hav done,i did what u said but it doesnt seems to work :(

Comment: @user1667217. The same code worked for me. I mean the windows bar still stays invisible. Is it also correct for you? Which version of JavafX are you using? Check it by System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());

Comment: it looks like my version is 2.1.0-b21, but i already figured it out how to make it, i just had to change the root thank for your time and help :D

Comment: Toggle fullscreen works, but there is "Press ESC to exit fullscreen" message shown. And this message cannot be disabled:(

Answer (score 0):

I am making a game as well, and I needed fullscreen functionality. The way I solved it was by:

1: using `primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);` to enable fullscreen of the main scene.

2: when changing to another scene, apply `primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);` again directly after setting the new scene.

My example:

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            // Start of program
            setUpGame();

            // MENU
            // Setting up menu stage
            primaryStage.setTitle("My cool game");
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
            primaryStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");

            // Setting up grid pane
            mod.getMenuGrid().setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            mod.getMenuGrid().setHgap(10);
            mod.getMenuGrid().setVgap(10);
            mod.getMenuGrid().setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

            ... More code until I'm changing scene ... 
    }

    private void startGame(Stage primaryStage) {
        setNames();
        createPlayers();
        setUpGameScene();
        primaryStage.setScene(mod.getGameScene());
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best way around it, but at least it's simple and it works.You just have to apply the line of code consistently when changing scenes.