# How to change scene when in fullscreen in JavaFX and avoid "Press ESC to exit fullscreen" message

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

How is it possible to change scene of fullscreen window and avoid to show "Press ESC to exit fullscreen" message?

I'm building fullscreen desktop application (touchscreen kiosk) so I can show this message at the beginning, but now always when user changes scene.

There are two problems:

1. When in fullscreen and scene is changed, window size is reduced.
   Solution is to toggle fullscreen, but there is that message shown. ([Change scene in full screen JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723664/change-scene-in-full-screen-javafx))
2. "Press ESC.." message cannot be disable due to security reasons (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2287258)

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

JavaFX 8 has solved this problem with the addition of the following 2 methods:

- [Stage.setFullScreenExitHint(String)](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreenExitHint-java.lang.String-)
- [Stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination)](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreenExitKeyCombination-javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination-)

If you set the exit key combination to `KeyCombination.NO_MATCH` the pop-up message will be disabled completely.

Answer (score 3):

on 2. there's going to be a new feature in JavaFX8 to turn that warning of. The current proposal is that there's going to be a command line option. You can see the discussion on the openjfx mailing list (http://markmail.org/search/?q=+javafx.Stage.fullScreenWarning%3Dfalse#query:%20javafx.Stage.fullScreenWarning%3Dfalse+page:1+mid:ptqpgut2vvvhgkip+state:results)

Comment: Thanks. It will be released on 2nd June? Available there - https://jdk8.java.net/download.html ?

Comment: why on 2nd june? Java8 is delayed until March 2014

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;

public class GameApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        StackPane stackPane=new StackPane();
        Scene scene=new Scene(stackPane,500,500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Title");
        //Fullscreen
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        //We don't want to exit the fullscreen when keys are pressed
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        //We are adding a change listener to lock the application in full
        //screen mode only
        stage.fullScreenProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                    Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if(newValue != null && !newValue.booleanValue())
                    stage.setFullScreen(true);
            }
        });
        stage.show();
    }
    //main method
    public static void main(String ...$){
        launch($);
    }
}
```