# What is the main role of the scene in javafx?

Tags: javafx, scene

A stage in javafx requires exactly one scene, and a scene requires exactly one root node. 
So I want to know what's the main role of the scene? It seems like a scene connects two sides that can be connected directly without an intermediate. 
I want juste to understand the logic. 
Thank you.

Comment: Just read the Javadocs and look at the properties belonging to a `Scene`. E.g. a `Scene` has a list of stylesheets, so if you change the root of a scene, the same stylesheets will be applied to the new root. (Conversely, if you change the scene entirely, you'd get a new set of stylesheets.) There are other differences between changing the scene and changing the root of the scene, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673607/javafx-changing-scenes-on-fullscreen-mode

Answer (score 1):

`Stage` represents a native system window. `Scene` is the content of this window with JavaFX controls, nodes, stylesheets, etc.

You can change Scenes inside a Stage during your UI workflow without a need to create a new system window each time.